# R order observations across columns

Tags: r, sorting, data-mining

I have a list of households, and the dates that they moved into a new ZIP Code. A small segment is as follows:

```
ADD0 <- as.Date(c("2008-07-01", "1998-07-01", "2001-11-01", "1997-08-01"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
ADD1 <- as.Date(c(NA, "2001-09-01", "2002-03-01", NA), format="%Y-%m-%d")
ADD2 <- as.Date(c(NA, "1992-09-01", "2001-09-01", "2007-12-01"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
ZIP0 <- as.character(c(30126, 30345, 30068, 30253))
ZIP1 <- as.character(c(NA, 30263, 31064, NA))
ZIP2 <- as.character(c(NA, 30345, 30067,30062))
DF <- data.frame(ADD0, ZIP0, ADD1, ZIP1, ADD2, ZIP2)
> DF
        ADD0  ZIP0       ADD1  ZIP1       ADD2  ZIP2
1 2008-07-01 30126       <NA>  <NA>       <NA>  <NA>
2 1998-07-01 30345 2001-09-01 30263 1992-09-01 30345
3 2001-11-01 30068 2002-03-01 31064 2001-09-01 30067
4 1997-08-01 30253       <NA>  <NA> 2007-12-01 30062
```

So house 2 moved in July '98, September '01, and September '92. My problem, as you can see, is that the dates are not necessarily in the correct order, and I need them to be. The only way I can see to do this is to loop through the dataset and write my own sort algorithm, something I have very little experience with. Efficiency is also important, because I have 450k observations.

Has anybody done this kind of thing before? Any tips? Is there a clean solution that I haven't been able to find?

Comment: What is wrong with **preprocessing** your data once to sort it into the right order? You'll have to iterate over it at least once anyway, and the sorting is as cheap as it can be. You do not need to invent your own sorting algorithm!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean; I am asking how I might go about preprocessing my data. I do not see it as a simple sort task, because that typically involves sorting a vector. I believe the answer I accepted provides precisely the solution I was hoping to get; do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the base `reshape` package, i would add a column `house` then reshape the data long.  Then order it.

```
DF$house <- row.names(DF)
df.long <- reshape(DF, 
                   idvar='house', 
                   varying=list(c('ADD0', 'ADD1', 'ADD2'),
                                c('ZIP0', 'ZIP1', 'ZIP2')),
                   v.names=c('add', 'zip'), 
                   timevar=NULL, 
                   direction='long')
df.long <- df.long[order(df.long$house, df.long$add),]


    house        add   zip
1.1     1 2008-07-01 30126
1.2     1       <NA>  <NA>
1.3     1       <NA>  <NA>
2.3     2 1992-09-01 30345
2.1     2 1998-07-01 30345
2.2     2 2001-09-01 30263
3.3     3 2001-09-01 30067
3.1     3 2001-11-01 30068
3.2     3 2002-03-01 31064
4.1     4 1997-08-01 30253
4.3     4 2007-12-01 30062
4.2     4       <NA>  <NA>
>
```

Comment: I really like this solution. To restore it to the `wide` format I need for other parts of the analysis, I used `desc()` on the `$add` vector, appended an address number with `df.long$add.num <- sequence(table(df.long$house))`, and then reshaped again with `df.wide <- reshape(df.long, idvar="house", timevar="add.num")

Comment: I feel I should also mention that the point I was missing, aside from the simplicity of the `reshape` command (which I have used before), was using a `list` for the `varying` option. I would never have arrived at this independently.

Comment: You could also do this in two melt steps.  `melt(DF, id.var='house', measure.var=c('ADD0', 'ADD1', 'ADD2'), value.name='add')` and then `merge` on house... but that seems much clunkier.

Answer (score 0):

A loop based solution that is probably pretty slow, but keeps your format.

```
DF <- data.frame(ADD0, ZIP0, ADD1, ZIP1, ADD2, ZIP2, stringsAsFactors = F)
DF2 = DF

for (i in 1:nrow(DF)){ 
  DF2[i,] =  DF[i,
    rep(order( DF[i,1:(ncol(DF) / 2) * 2 -1])*2, each = 2) + (-1:0)] 
}
```

I agree with the other answerer though. I think the core cause of difficulty here is the way the data is being stored here, which is pretty unhelpful to work with.

Comment: It's unhelpful to work with for this step; but other steps in the process require that the data be on a single row.